# Order of CAST() and COALESCE() matters in MariaDB

Tags: sql, casting, mariadb, coalesce

I have a strange problem: There is a price in a JSON column in a table and the following statements give different results while they should give the same thing:

```sql
CAST(COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(item.price_details, "$.shipping.price"), 0) AS FLOAT) AS shippricecoalfloat

COALESCE(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(item.price_details, "$.shipping.price") AS FLOAT), 0) AS shippricefloatcoal
```

Just to check I also added a `JSON_EXTRACT(item.price_details, "$.shipping.price") AS shipprice`

Result:

[image: results]

MariaDB version: `mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.31-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

[DB Fiddle (I couldn't use the same MariaDB version but it behaves the same anyways apparently)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=6b6662f28a974dabe77de1ce21e6b316)

Comment: This is going to be implicit casting based on order of precedence, you are passing two different data types to `coalesce` - what happens if you pass `'0'` as a string to match the json value?

Comment: I just tested and I get exactly the same results.

Comment: It's not easy to also test as you haven't provided any sample data, can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) perhaps using DB<>Fiddle

Comment: I added a fiddle

Comment: It's a nuisance that MySQL and MariaDB don't throw an error when converting an invalid string to number. `"0.8648"` is not a number. `0.8648` is. You are right that both expressions should return the same result. That is 0, because this is the result when casting a non-numeric string in those DBMS. I cannot explain, why the second expression results in 0.8648 instead. It shouldn't.

Comment: On a side note: Don't cast to `FLOAT` when not absolutely necessary. `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` are approximate data types that you'll hardly ever need in a database. Use `DECIMAL` with an appropriate precision as a precise type instead (e.g. `CAST(... AS DECIMAL(10,4))`.

Comment: The second expression results in a value as `CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(price_details, "$.shipping.price") AS FLOAT)` result in a valid float value `0.8648`, whereas directly casting the string value containing quotes results in `0`

Comment: Everyone is missing that `JSON_EXTRACT()` returns JSON Objects. Scalar Values are returned by `JSON_VALUE()`.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit: this is a DB at my job I have no control over; of course I agree this value should be stored as a number and not a string but I can't do anything about it unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong JSON function.

`JSON_EXTRACT()` returns a JSON Object found at that path. That's why in your fiddle you still see double quotes.

You want to return a scalar value from a specific path. So, use `JSON_VALUE()`

```
SELECT
    item_id,
    JSON_VALUE(price_details, "$.shipping.price") AS shipprice,
    CAST(COALESCE(JSON_VALUE(price_details, "$.shipping.price"), '0') AS FLOAT) AS shippricecoalfloat,
    COALESCE(CAST(JSON_VALUE(price_details, "$.shipping.price") AS FLOAT), 0) AS shippricefloatcoal
FROM `item`
WHERE order_id = 109517;
```

Also, part of the "mess" with datatypes is caused by your JSON storing some values as strings with double quotes, and some as numeric values. I strongly recommend not enclosing numeric values in double quotes in your JSON.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=d67fa297a5cc4248a06750d71581c022

- added extra expression to show what happens if coalescing a float with an integer, vs a float with a float

Comment: Thanks, someone used `JSON_EXTRACT` instead of `JSON_VALUE` and I didn't catch the mistake. I also have no control over the DB unfortunately so I can't fix the string instead of number problem.

Comment: Then you need to be aware that json will allow `"0.8FUBAR648"` but not `0.8FUBAR648`.  This can mean that you may not get the results you expect.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=7c840ffa5844bd484467dc9d59deb8a9

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is "the solution" for your question:

```
select cast('"0.8648"' as float)
```

I will try to explain how I see it...
First thing to know is: "COALESCE() has the same data type as the argument."
This `COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(price_details, "$.shipping.price"), 0) as coal` returns "0.8648" but as a string(varchar) so it returns '"0.8648"'

This `CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(price_details, "$.shipping.price") AS FLOAT) as caast` returns 0.8648 so no problems there...

This `select cast('"0.8648"' as float)` returns 0 which is the same as your result...

You can not cast a value with double quotes in it to a float.
You will get a result when you coalesce float value and 0 equal to that float value.

I believe this explains it ?

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=84e00d2929b47f95cf5d6628d0e798f7)

Maybe as addition to this I should ask/say isn't this "098" same as this '098' ?

Comment: The reason the double quotes are being included is that `JSON_EXTRACT()` returns JSON Objects, but `JSON_VALUE()` returns scalar values.

Comment: Also, JSON specification is to use double quotes not single quotes. But, for numerical values the op should use neither, they're storing strings instead of numbers.

Comment: Ok, but my answer explains why cast and coalesce return different results and your answer goes deeper right ? Is there something wrong in my answer ?

Comment: It's not a string. You only think it's a string because of how it's displayed on screen. It's a json object.  So, `cast('"0.8648"' as float)` isn't representative, because that's a string, but the Op's code is coercing json datatypes.

Comment: Ok, but it comes to a same thing right ? CASR of both string(with double quotes) and JSON object will return 0 ?

Comment: No. JSON datatypes behave entirely differently from strings/longtext/varchar, etc. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=5b719f1759ffb7a37a7ed9ca47383e96

Comment: Sorry I have written it wrong. Coalesce of the cast of the json_extract value will give the same result as cast of the string with double  quotes. 0. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=bf19beb69ae78389a142105a58cc8fd7 And that is just one way I was going with - to show that cast and coalesce are working ok.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to assert.  But, if you have `"0.8648"` as a string, it won't cast to a float because of the double quotes.  But when it's a json type, it will cast to a float, even though the `"` are there.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=809e8e6b6e6a37e717328fda67327393  `JSON`, however, can't be coalesced, and reverts to `longtext`.  As such `CAST(COALESCE(json, something) AS FLOAT)` acts like `CAST(string AS FLOAT)` but not the same as `CAST(json AS FLOAT)` *(which 'works')*.